# Where did the "favorites" tab go?

Tags: mac, finder

[image]

Normally there is a "favorites" tab on the left side where I can easily navigate from folder to folder...where did it go? Not sure if this is just me being stupid and accidentally disabling it, or if it disappeared on me when I updated to El Capitan.

Answer (score 1):

Check the **Finder Preferences** to see if you have anything selected under Favorites.

From the **Finder Menu**

- Select **Finder > Preferences...**
- Select the **Sidebar** tab
- Tick the boxes under Favorites that you wish to see in the Sidebar.

The **Sidebar** is the area on the left side.

[image: Finder Preferences - Sidebar]